# Meaning of charges in a group?

Tags: oxidation-state, periodic-trends

In my class, my professor said that since hydrogen is in group one, it has a charge of 1+. Does this refer to its ionic charge or to its oxidation state?

Comment: Actually, both. Note, however, that hydrogen may be -1 as well.

Comment: @Atticus283blink - you seem to be struggling with terminology.  Writing out definitions on flash cards and periodically testing yourself, or using an app like ankidroid, may greatly improve your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

To go from being confused to less confused, here are some facts.

- Hydrogen has one valence electron which can participate in reactions so it is ***a group 1 element***.
- Hydrogen is not a ***group 1 alkali metal***, nor is it a ***group 1 compound***, so simply stating hydrogen is in ***group 1***  is ambiguous and confusing.  It is a ***group 1 element***.  The word ***element*** needs to be included for the statement to make any sense.
- Elemental hydrogen has no charge at standard conditions because it exists as dihydrogen gas, $\ce{H2}$.  If hydrogen gas were to be ionized it could hypothetically break into two ions, one with a +1 charge and one with a -1 charge.  If no ions are involved then the concept of ionic charge is irrelevant.
- Elemental hydrogen, again as dihydrogen gas, $\ce{H2}$, has a zero oxidation state.  The oxidation state refers to a hypothetical charge of an element within a compound. If no compound is involved then oxidation states are irrelevant.
- Elemental hydrogen has an oxidation state of +1 in most compounds and -1 in metal hydrides because of an agreement within the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC). -- http://goldbook.iupac.org/O04365.html --  Oxidation states, as many of the concepts in basic chemistry, should be viewed as a tool to gain a rudimentary understanding of how compounds form.

Answer (score -1):

The utility (usefulness) of the Periodic Table is beyond question. I've used it a couple of times during my career as a chemist - but ONLY a couple of times (in 40+ years). It is unquestionably most useful in school, for those learning the similarities (and differences) between the properties and characteristics of the elements. So, it is a "guide", not a "rule book". What you wrote isn't quite correct - possibly your professor is being sloppy - in a philosophical sense. H is in Group 1 because it usually ionizes to the cation (+1 charged ion) and not the other way around (it doesn't ionize to +1 because it is in Group 1!!). For individual atoms there is no difference between its ionic charge and oxidiation state. When atoms are combined into groups (via covalent bonding (which is by definition (at least partial) sharing of electrons) things get more ambiguous. Even IUPAC confuses the terms Oxidation State and Oxidation number. Ionic charge can be assigned to a single atom in a group, but it almost never is an integer number (some charge sharing is going on). The most straightforward was to assign charge is via crystallographic or quantum mechanical computational methods, neither are useful as you stand at the lab bench with a new compound wondering if it is charged and if so, how. OK, I've digressed a long way from your question. "Oxidation state" is generally done by assuming that all bonds are pure ionic (which is almost never true, virtually all bonds are a mix of ionic and covalent). "Formal charge" assumes just the 'opposite', that all bonds are 50:50 shared between the two atoms (which is only applicable to bonds between identical atoms each of which is in an identical environment (eg H2, N2, and the C-C bond in H3C-CH3). So, the Periodic Table is justified BECAUSE IT WORKS but now we usually explain it by explaining how atoms are built up (Aufbau Principle) and electrons populate the orbitals (maybe with a bow to Quantum Mechanics). Perhaps your professor meant: if you look at the Periodic Table, and see that H is in G1, then you should *assume* it will bond with an oxidation state of +1. (That is, you predict this based on the PT as a "guide"). As an example of where this works, consider HCl. In aqueous solution it exists, they tell you, as H+ and Cl-. So, the guide works. (I won't mention the fact that H+ doesn't 'exist' in solution and what we mean by H+(aq) is H(+)n(H2O) (n = 1, 2, 3...) nor that HCl in the gas phase is covalent) If you just assume H is ionized to H+, you'll get the *STOICHIOMETRY* right, which is an important goal for beginners. (in some compounds, H exists as the hydride H(-), this is especially true in the Sun's atmosphere - google it!) So there will be situations where the periodic table lets you down, but you gotta start somewhere. Consider H in H2O. According to your professor, it will be composed of two H+ cations and one O= anion. So, it should conduct one heck of a lot of electricity. But pure water is quite nonconductive (if it is very pure). It is correct to claim that the oxidation state of the Hs in H2O are both +1, it is very wrong to claim that they are both (really) ionized to +1. (It is also correct to say their formal charge is 0, each H has one H-O bond (2 electrons in a covalent bond) and has no other electrons. So,(remembering each covalent bond is split ½:½ for determination of formal charge), 2 * ½ = 1 it has 1 (formal) electron (-1) and its nucleus is +1 giving a formal charge of +1 -1 = 0. ) Let me try to bottom-line this. A particle has an ionic charge. That particle might be an ion or an atom or a molecule (actually if charge is non-zero we could also call it either an ion or a molecular ion). When you rub your feet on a carpet YOU pick up a charge; you've got a charge and NOT an "oxidation state". Oxidation state can be used for single atoms, (in which case its same as ionic charge, so why bother?) but is generally used for atoms in bigger assemblages → which means oxidation state is most useful in dividing up the electrons in a group particle (in a compound ion). The Periodic Table can be useful (as a guide) for both.

Comment: Hi - I noticed you currently have several different accounts ([1](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/32390/li-zhi),[2](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/36395/li-zhi),[3](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/36397/li-zhi)) on the network. If you would like to get these merged into one single account, just follow the steps [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and the SE team will get it done for you. If you've forgotten your password, that page I linked also contains a password recovery option. Thanks.